# Flink job listener - not returning job execution result in openshift

Tags: java, openshift, apache-flink, flink-batch

Trying to use the flink job listener for notifying batch end.

But the job is running in openshift as default detached mode.

How to get the job status and other metrics on job executed in job manager.

Tried all possible ways.its not coming to job listener itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.